# Laravel: View [layouts.default] not found

Tags: php, laravel-4

I installed a bundle in my project that defines it's own views. While navigating through the site after making some changes, I found that all of my actions that happen with the bundled views work fine, but when I go back to the head route, I get an error message:

```
View [layouts.default] not found. (View: /var/www/app/views/home.blade.php)
```

The file `app/views/home.blade.php` definitely exists. The closure for my head route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', function()
{
    return View::make('home');
}));
```

What could have changed the structure of my views?

EDIT:

Here's the contents of my home.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

{{-- Web site Title --}}
@section('title')
@parent
{{trans('pages.helloworld')}}
@stop

{{-- Content --}}
@section('content')

<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>{{trans('pages.helloworld')}}</h1>
    <p>{{trans('pages.description')}}</p>
  </div>
</div>

@if (Sentry::check() )
    <div class="panel panel-success">
         <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> {{trans('pages.loginstatus')}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p><strong>{{trans('pages.sessiondata')}}:</strong></p>
            <pre>{{ var_dump(Session::all()) }}</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif 


@stop
```

Comment: Can we see your `home.blade.php`?

Comment: When you say see, do you mean in the browser?

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz No, the content.

Comment: Sorry, I read that wrong. Yeah I'll update my post

Comment: It says that `View [layouts.default] not found.` so is it wrong ? don't you have `layouts/default.blade.php` ?

Comment: You said `after making some changes`, what changes you've made, what is the default `view` path is set ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha yes that view does exist as well, though it's part of the installed package so it's located at `app/views/packages/rydurham/sentinel/layouts/default.blade.php`

Comment: I added several form fields to one of the published package views. Those fields show correctly in the browser.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz How on earth would Laravel know that your `layouts` folder is located inside `packages/rydurham/sentinel`?

Comment: @Linek, sorry, this the first phase in my first laravel project. I'm still accumulating understanding of the framework.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

File `layouts.default` does not exists.

See:

```
@extends('layouts.default')
```

First line.

What Laravel does it looks for a directory `layouts` inside a `views` directory and tries to load `default` file inside. This file does not exist so the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks. I used to have a copy of the layouts folder at the root level of my views folder and I cleaned it out after understanding that it needed to live in the published packages folder. I altered the extended path to point to `packages.rydurham.sentinel.layouts.default.blade.php` which took care of the problem.