# View [layouts.default] not found - Laravel

Tags: laravel, layout, view

I am trying to run my laravel project but it showing error that view not found.

My welcome.blade.php file is

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
<div class="slider">
    <div class="img-responsive">
        <ul class="bxslider">               
            <li><img src="images/slider/1.jpg" alt=""/></li>                                
            <li><img src="images/slider/2.jpg" alt=""/></li>    
            <li><img src="images/slider/3.jpg" alt=""/></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-offset="0" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
            <h3>Providing Our Clients</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-offset="0" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
            <h2>Best & Creative Solutions</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Updated

[you can see error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDa47.png)

[file structure see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Naf.png)

Comment: Is the layout for sure under `resources/views/layouts`? Is the name of the layout file for sure `default.blade.php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: View \[layouts.default\] not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144197/laravel-view-layouts-default-not-found)

Comment: @Neeya can u show us the error ?

Comment: my file name is default.blade.php

Comment: @Neeya can u take snapshot of the error you are getting and post it here

Comment: @Maraboc question is duplicate but i refer same question to solve my query but i hadnt got solution

Comment: @MazinoSUkah i have upload screenshoot of my error please have a look on that

Comment: @Neeya check your layouts folder (under views) and verify that you have a layout file named " default.blade.php ". You need to place the "default.blade.php" file in the layouts folder

Comment: Why ? Did you have `layouts.default` that you extends here `@extends('layouts.default')` !!

Comment: @MazinoSUkah please have a look on my file structure

Comment: Your linked structure indicates it should be `layout.default` (without the `s` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay just looked at your folder structure, rename your layout folder to "layouts". hope that helps.